# Index Hint is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I m trying to learn about index hint, but even after providing hint in query its not been used. Here's steps I followed, am I missing something?

```
SQL> desc emp_1;
Name     Type         Nullable Default Comments 
-------- ------------ -------- ------- -------- 
EMP_ID   NUMBER                                 
EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(20) Y                         
DEPTNO   NUMBER(10)   Y               


SQL> desc dept
Name      Type         Nullable Default Comments 
--------- ------------ -------- ------- -------- 
DEPT_ID   NUMBER       Y                         
DEPT_NAME VARCHAR2(20) Y                         


SQL> CREATE INDEX abc_idex ON emp_1 (deptno);

Index created

select  /*+ index(emp_1.abc_idex) */ emp_name from emp_1
INNER JOIN dept ON  emp_1.deptno = dept.dept_id
```

Explain Plan :-

```
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS           6   1   28
 HASH JOIN          6   1   28
  TABLE ACCESS FULL EXAMINBI    EMP_1   2   1   25
  TABLE ACCESS FULL EXAMINBI    DEPT    3   4   12
```

As per Rene's answer

```
select  /*+ index(emp_1 abc_idex) */ emp_name from emp_1
INNER JOIN dept ON  emp_1.deptno = dept.dept_id
```

Explain Plan

```
SELECT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS           271 100000  800000
 MERGE JOIN         271 100000  800000
  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   EXAMINBI    EMP_1   267 100000  500000
   INDEX FULL SCAN  EXAMINBI    ABC_IDEX    131 100000  
  SORT JOIN         4   4   12
   TABLE ACCESS FULL    EXAMINBI    DEPT    3   4   12
```

Comment: @ Rene - I added around 100000 records in emp_1 table, anyways it should not matter as I m giving explicit hint here.. @Mat I m just trying to learn about indexes so its kind of self learning at this point.. I have copied all commands from sql prompt.

Comment: can we have the updated SQL hint, I'm trying to use IndexHint, however could not execute it in Rapid Idera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Tahitis documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50405), you must not put a `.` between the *table spec* and the *index spec*.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine.. I have added new explain plan in answer.. Thanks